# Chrome Extension that take srolling screenshot but fails to work without error message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screenshot, html2canvas

I am a dummy in making chrome extension. I'm trying to make a chrome extension that has the following functionality: 1.take a screenshot of the current page;  2. take a scrolling screenshot by sroll down the srolling bar of the brower when the user chooses to do so;  3. the screenshot will be saved to desktop as a png file.

Here is my code.

- manifest.json

  ```
  {
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "SrollShot",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Take screenshots and scrolling screenshots.",
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "downloads"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon-16.png",
      "48": "icon-48.png",
      "128": "icon-128.png"
    }
  }
  ```
- background.js

  ```
  // background.js

  // Listen for messages from the popup
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === "takeScreenshot") {
      // Get the active tab ID
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        const tabId = tabs[0]?.id;
        if (tabId) {
          // Send a message to the content script to take a screenshot
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            function: () => {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: "screenshot" });
            },
          });
        }
      });
    } else if (message.action === "scrollingScreenshot") {
      // Get the active tab ID
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        const tabId = tabs[0]?.id;
        if (tabId) {
          // Send a message to the content script to take a scrolling screenshot
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            function: () => {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: "scrollingScreenshot" });
            },
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // Rest of your background script code...
  ```
- content_script.js

  ```
  // content_script.js

  // Check if the current URL is not a Chrome internal URL (chrome://)
  if (!location.href.startsWith("chrome://")) {
    // Listen for messages from the background script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (message.action === "screenshot") {
        // Take a screenshot of the current visible area
        takeScreenshot(function (screenshotData) {
          sendResponse({ screenshotData });
        });
        return true; // Indicates that we will respond asynchronously
      } else if (message.action === "scrollingScreenshot") {
        // Take a scrolling screenshot
        takeScrollingScreenshot(function (screenshotData) {
          sendResponse({ screenshotData });
        });
        return true; // Indicates that we will respond asynchronously
      }
    });

    function takeScreenshot(callback) {
      // ... rest of the takeScreenshot function (unchanged) ...
    }

    function takeScrollingScreenshot(callback) {
      // ... rest of the takeScrollingScreenshot function (unchanged) ...
    }
  }
  ```
- popup.js

  ```
  // popup.js

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("takeScreenshotBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "takeScreenshot" });
    });

    document.getElementById("takeScrollingScreenshotBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "scrollingScreenshot" });
    });
  });
  ```
- popup.html

  ```
  <!-- popup.html -->
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>SrollShot</title>
    <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="takeScreenshotBtn">Take Screenshot</button>
    <button id="takeScrollingScreenshotBtn">Take Scrolling Screenshot</button>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

The script makes use of html2canvas, in my case, when i toggle on and click the extention icon, it works as expected, popping up an option of "take screenshot" and "take srolling screenshot", but after I click either option button, nothing happens and no error pops up. It should automatically take a screeenshot and save it to the computer.

I tried to track the error, but when I click the icon and the option button(i.e. to try to take screenshot) on the tagpage of the extention manager, i get an "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL" error, which i could understand. But when I tried to take screenshot of other normal webpage, nothing happens, and the extention manager shows no error message.

I don't know what is problem.

Do you have an idea??

Comment: Remove chrome.scripting.executeScript in background.js and just call chrome.tabs.sendMessage directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried to call chrome.tabs.sendMessage directly, and after i click "take screenshot" button, the extention manager shows a new error, 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist'.

Comment: Then keep executeScript but instead of func use `files: ['content_script.js'] }, () => { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(........) })`